# Builder options on Ruby Nokogiri :standalone

Tags: ruby, xml, nokogiri

I would like to to create XML that begins with:

```
<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone ="no"?>
```

But I cannot find how to add the '`standalone`' option in the Nokogiri documentation.

My code is like this:

```
builder = Nokogiri::XML::Builder.new(:encoding => 'UTF-8', :standalone => 'no') do |xml|
```

But it fails when Nokogiri finds `:standalone`. The `:encoding` works.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The way around this is to tell Nokogiri::XML::Builder to use an existing XML document by using the [`with`](http://nokogiri.org/Nokogiri/XML/Builder.html#method-c-with) method:

```
xml = Nokogiri::XML('<?xml version = "1.0" encoding = "UTF-8" standalone ="no"?>')
puts Nokogiri::XML::Builder.with(xml) { |x| x.awesome }.to_xml

<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="no"?>
<awesome/>
```